# Typescript : How to overload a protected class constant

Tags: typescript, class, extends, super

With typescript, when defining classes with inheritance, is it possible to overload a protected constant ?

Exemple :

```
class A {
   static defaultProps = {
      message: ''
   }
}

class B extends A {
   static defaultProps = {
      // get defaultProps from A,
      title: ''
   }
}
```

I don't know if it's important that I'm working with React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just extend the `defaultProps` prop from `A` class (note: the `defaultProps` is ˙static` so you can access that on the class not on the instance)

The following should work:

```
class A {
   static defaultProps = {
      message: ''
   }
}

class B extends A {
   static defaultProps = {
      ...A.defaultProps,
      title: ''
   }
}
```